# get object from markdown

Tags: markdown

Most markdown libraries convert a markdown string to a html-string oder binary (pdf, tex).

Is there a markdown library which returns a object? I need this to create a Table of Contents, edit single section (like [edit section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Section#Section_editing)) or section transclusion (like [Labeled Section Transclusion](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Labeled_Section_Transclusion).

### Example

```
# MyHead
Some Text
* list one 
* list two
sea takimata sanctus
## Deeper Head
At vero eos
# other Head
lorem ipsum
# MyHead
sea takimata
```

should return something like this:

```
{
    "MyHead_1": {
        "Heading_1": "MyHead",
        "Paragraph_1": "Some Text",
        "List_1": ["list one", "list two"],
        "Deeper_Head_1": {
            "Heading_2": "Deeper Head",
            "Paragraph_1": "At vero eos"
        }
    },
    "other Head_1": {
        "Heading_1": "other Head",
        "Paragraph_1": "lorem ipsum"
    },
    "MyHead_2": {
        "Heading_1": "MyHead",
        "Paragraph_1": "sea takimata"
    }
}
```

Comment: HTML-like? Isn't that rather JSON-like?

Comment: A JSON string that represents the HTML? Although the HTML-snippet is already arguably an object (DOM)?

Comment: @Izzy html-like was missleading. I just want to got an object back, no matter the format.

Comment: @w3d  yes html is an object, this is god for rg the toc. But I want the markdown as object.( e.g. for section transclusion)